# How to revert to original line after using \n in a string in Java?

Tags: java, string

```
System.out.println("\tName: " + lastName +", " + firstAndMiddleName);
System.out.println("\tBalance Owed: "+ df.format(PV));
System.out.println("\tInterest Rate: " + apr+ "%");
System.out.println("\n\tYears" + "\tMonthly \n\t\tPayment" + "\tInterest" + "\tTotal Amount");
System.out.print("\n\tYears" + "\tMonthly \n\t\tPayment" + "\tInterest" + "\tTotal Amount");
```

This is what I have, but I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to format it right.  This is how I want it to look:

ex.

```
          Monthly                Total
 Years    Payment    Interest    Amount
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at [`String#format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) and the [Format String Syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax)

Comment: Can't do it the way you're thinking. MadProgrogrammer's suggestion should help. Also look up how to display / format reports in java.

Comment: You have to print two separate lines (with "... Monthly ... Total" on the top line), or use some sort of GUI presentation facility.

Comment: (Reverse line feed was only an option on some old "big iron" printers from the 60s.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As MadProgrammer said, you can use Format String Syntax which would require two print lines in order to achieve what you want.

Each "Print Line" will be used for a row, so Monthly and Total will be from the first and the rest on the second. Be careful tho since you'll need to output empty spaces on the top row for those ones that don't have a first row entry.

For example, to just do:

```
       Total
    Interest
```

It would be like:

```
System.out.println(String.format("%12s", "Total"));
System.out.println(String.format("%12s", "Interest"));
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to do string formatting?  Sorry, I just started my CS degree this year so my knowledge is a little hit and miss.  What is the % sign signify?  I though it had to do with modulo?

Comment: I suggest reading the what MadProgrammer posted. (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) However, the String.format will format what is passed in as a String that is 12 characters long. (As identified by %12s) In this case I pass in total which is only 5 characters so it pads the left with empty spaces to achieve the formatting I desire. % is used in modular division when performing math operations. It is used in other places throughout java.

Comment: Actually I figured it out!  Thank you very much for the insight!

Answer (score 0):

You could just print the whole line and add spaces between "monthly" and "total"

`System.out.println ("              Monthly                              Total");

System.out.println '("years    payement       interest     amount");`